# Как достать текст из entry Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Я создаю большое количество entry (использую tkinter) вот код -

```
for i in range(1,31):
    entries["EntryNumber{0}".format(i)]=Entry().place(relx=x_for_entry, rely=y_for_entry, anchor="c")
```

Далее мне нужно из каждого entry вытаскивать текст , так же в цикле . Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Вызвать метод `get()` у каждого экземпляра Entry. `for i in range(1,31):
    print(  entries["EntryNumber{0}".format(i)].get()   )`. Только в вашем словаре сейчас сплошные `None`, т.к. `place()` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: если бы все было так просто , я бы сюда не писал. Я уже пробовал , ошибка - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Ну я и сказал, что у вас там будут сплошные `None`.

Comment: не знаете как исправить?

Comment: все , я уже починил , просто place переместил:

Comment: entries["EntryNumber{0}".format(i)]=Entry()
  entries["EntryNumber{0}".format(i)].place(relx=x_for_entry, rely=y_for_entry, anchor="c")
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создание:

```
for i in range(1,31):
    entries[f"EntryNumber{i}"] = Entry()  # чтобы сохранить ссылку на виджет
    entries[f"EntryNumber{i}"].place(relx=x_for_entry, rely=y_for_entry, anchor="c")
```

Получение содержимого:

```
for i in range(1,31):
    print( entries[f"EntryNumber{i}"].get() )
```